# Detect scrolled height with jQuery.scroll()

Tags: jquery, scroll

I've got a #top-div that displays a "to the top of the site"-text. When I do the following code it works without the "else" - then the div is displayed after scrolling 700px.

But the "else" won't work, it won't display at all. The div should be hidden when you scroll up to the top of the site again.

Any help appreciated.

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    scrollet = $(window).scrollTop();
    if(scrollet > 700) {
        $("#top").animate({"opacity":"0.6"});
    }
    else {
        $("#top").animate({"opacity":"0"});
    }
```

Comment: So if you leave out the `else`-clause the code works, except for the top div never hiding again, and when you add the else clause it stops working?

Comment: Any errors in the console?

Comment: Yep, when I add the "else" it actually only displays if the refreshes the site while its scrolled to the bottom. But it doesn't hide if you scroll up.

No errors :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am suspecting that the animation is not working as intended as the animation effect has been queued when you scroll past the 700px boundary back and forth.

When using animation, it is important to tell jQuery to "drop what you're doing now, stop the animation queue and do as what you're told now". That means that you will have to chain the `.animate` behind a `.stop` method ([read about .stop()](http://api.jquery.com/stop/)), i.e.:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    scrollet = $(window).scrollTop();
    if(scrollet > 700) {
        $("#top").stop(true, false).animate({"opacity":"0.6"});
    }
    else {
        $("#top").stop(true, false).animate({"opacity":"0"});
    }
}
```

The `.stop(true, false)` method forces jQuery to clear the animation queue and but does not force the element jump to the end of the animation - this is because the `.scroll()` event is fired more than once when a user scrolls. If we use `.stop(true, true)` the transition will be abrupt.

Alternatives include:

- [Debouncing or throttling](http://benalman.com/code/projects/jquery-throttle-debounce/docs/files/jquery-ba-throttle-debounce-js.html) the `.scroll()` event
- Don't use `.animate()`, but simply set opacity using CSS and take advantage of CSS transitions, e.g. `transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out`.

Here is a proof-of-concept fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/teddyrised/zdpMd/

Comment: Oh, and I forgot to mention that the animation will not actually work too well - because the `.scroll()` event is triggered very frequently when a user scrolls through the page, causing the opacity to switch abruptly - so instead of forcing the browser to jump to the final appearance, try using `.stop(true, false)`.